# Replace single quotes with double quotes in python, for use with insert into database

Tags: python, insert

Was wondering whether anyone has a clever solution for fixing bad
insert statements in Python, exported by a not so clever program. It didn't add
two single quotes for strings with a single quote in the string. To
make it a bit easier all the values being inserted are strings.

So it has:

```
INSERT INTO addresses VALUES ('1','1','CUCKOO'S NEST','CUCKOO'S NEST STREET');
```

instead of:

```
INSERT INTO addresses VALUES ('1','1','CUCKOO''S NEST','CUCKOO''S NEST STREET');
```

Obviously there are multiple lines of this and I don't want to replace
the enclosing single quotes as well.

Was thinking of using split and join, but I'm not sure how to easily update the split values while looping in a loop. Sorry I'm a noob. Something like the below, where I'm not sure how to do #update bit

```
import sys

fileIN = open('a.sql', "r")
line = fileIN.readline()

while line:
   bits = line.split("','")
   for bit in bits:
      if bit.find("'") > -1:
         #update bit
   line_out = "','".join(bits)      
   sys.stdout.write(line_out)
   line = fileIN.readline()
```

Thanks

Comment: Horrible hack of the week: string replace `('` by `("`, `')` by `")` and `','` by `","`. Might work.

Comment: Oracle SQL wants single quotes I'm afraid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on katrielalex's suggestion, how about this:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "INSERT INTO addresses VALUES ('1','1','CUCKOO'S NEST','CUCKOO'S NEST STREET');"
>>> def repl(m):
    if m.group(1) in ('(', ',') or m.group(2) in (',', ')'):
        return m.group(0)
    return m.group(1) + "''" + m.group(2)

>>> re.sub("(.)'(.)", repl, s)
"INSERT INTO addresses VALUES ('1','1','CUCKOO''S NEST','CUCKOO''S NEST STREET');"
```

and if you're into negative lookbehind assertions, this is the headache inducing pure regex version:

```
re.sub("((?<![(,])'(?![,)]))", "''", s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while line:
    # Restrain line2 to inside parentheses
    line1, rest = line.split('(')
    line2, line3 = rest.split(')')
    # A bit more cleaner
    new_bits = []
    for bit in line2.split(','):
        # Remove border ' characters
        bit = bit[1:-1]
        # Duplicate the ones inside
        if "'" in bit:
            bit = bit.replace("'", "''")
        # Re-add border '
        new_bits.append("'" + bit + "'")
   sys.stdout.write(line1 + '(' + ','.join(new_bits + ')' + line3)
   line = fileIN.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: This depends *way* too much on the formatting of the SQL statement. However, if your input is only ever going to have the format "statements (params) end" then this will work every time.

```
import sys

fileIN = open('a.sql', "r")
line = fileIN.readline()

while line:
    #split out the parameters (between the ()'s)
    start, temp = line.split("(")
    params, end = temp.split(")")

    #replace the "'"s in the parameters (without the start and end quote)
    newParams = "','".join([x.replace("'", "''") for x in params[1:-1].split("','")])

    #join the statement back together
    line_out = start + "('" + newParams + "')" + end

    #next line
    sys.stdout.write(line_out)
    line = fileIN.readline()
```

Explanation:

1. Split the string into 3 parts: The query start, the parameters, and the end.
2. The generator takes the parameters (without the starting/ending `'`s), splits it on `','`, and, for every element in the list the split generates (the individual data entries), replaces the `'`s with `''`s.
3. The last line then joins the query start, the new params (with the parenthesis and quotes that were removed previously), and the end of the statement.

Comment: Looks nice and readable, but I'm afraid there must be lines with 2 insert statements on one line; because I get a "ValueError: too many values to unpack" on the start, temp = line.split("("). It is a 700Mb file of addresses, so a bit difficult to foresee all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer:

```
a = "INSERT INTO addresses VALUES ('1','1','CUCKOO'S NEST','CUCKOO'S NEST STREET');"
open_par = a.find("(")
close_par = a.find(")")
b = a[open_par+1:close_par]
c = b.split(",")
d = map(lambda x: '"' + x.strip().strip("'") + '"',c)
result = a[:open_par+1] + ",".join(d) + a[close_par:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Went with:

```
import sys
import re

def repl(m):
    if m.group(1) in ('(', ',') or m.group(2) in (',', ')'):
        return m.group(0)
    return m.group(1) + "''" + m.group(2)

fileIN = open('a.sql', "r")
line = fileIN.readline()

while line:
    line_out = re.sub("(.)'(.)", repl, line)
    sys.stdout.write(line_out)
    # Next line.
    line = fileIN.readline()
```